# Avoiding implicit conversion with concepts

Tags: c++, c++20, implicit-conversion, c++-concepts

Since templates and dynamic polymorphism don't mix well, I am currently designing a concept, instead of an interface (implemented with abstract class), for a `Loggable` type, which supports operations:

```
logger.log(LogLevel::info) << "some message" << 0 << 0.0 << 'c';
```

Provided the log levels defined:

```
enum class LogLevel
{
    info,
    warning,
    error
};
```

The concept looks like that:

```
template<typename T>
concept Loggable = requires(T v)
{
    {
        v.log(LogLevel{})
        } -> std::convertible_to<T&>;

    {
        v << "log message" << static_cast<unsigned>(0) << static_cast<int>(0) << static_cast<float>(0.0)
          << static_cast<unsigned char>(0) << static_cast<char>('0')
        } -> std::convertible_to<T&>;
};
```

To test a logger, the following function has been defined:

```
template<typename T>
requires Loggable<T>
void fun(T& v)
{
    v.log(LogLevel::error);
}
```

I have defined a `Logger`:

```
struct Logger1
{
    Logger1& log(LogLevel)
    {
        return *this;
    }

    Logger1& operator<<(float)
    {
        return *this;
    }

    Logger1& operator<<(std::string)
    {
        return *this;
    }
};
```

Then invoking the Logger with:

```
Logger1 l1{};
fun(l1);
```

Gives no compiler errors. This is because the string literal is implicitly cast to std::string and `unsigned`, `int`, `char`, `unsigned char` get eventually implicitly cast to `float`.

How can I:

1. Forbid implicit cast of `int`, `char`, `unsigned char`, `unsigned` to `float`, but ...
2. Still allow implicit cast of the string literal to `std::string`?

Comment: *"Since templates and dynamic polymorphism don't mix well"* - Type erasing handles have left the chat...

Comment: You could add to `Logger1`, `template <typename T> Logger1& operator<<(T) = delete;`.  That will stop any implicit conversions for that one logger.

Comment: I'm not sure what's the problem if the logger decide it want to handle `int` as `float`?

Comment: You might try to restrict with something like that: `static_cast<T& (T::*)(int)>(&T::operator<<);`...

Comment: @appleapple This is a good point and most probably my final solution will accept that. On the other hand I still wanted to know whether there is way to avoid implicit conversion ;)

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica what do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid implicit conversion, we can define a template `operator<<` that matches all other types.

In addition, in order to avoid blocking string literal, we can add a constraint for this `operator<<` to ensure that the operand cannot be converted to `std::string`:

```
#include <string>

template<typename T>
concept WeaklyLoggable = requires(T v) {
  { v.log(LogLevel{}) } -> std::convertible_to<T&>;
};

template<WeaklyLoggable T, class U>
  requires (!std::convertible_to<U, std::string>)
auto operator<<(T, U) = delete;

template<typename T>
concept Loggable = WeaklyLoggable<T> && requires(T v) {
  { 
     v << "log message"
       << static_cast<unsigned>(0) 
       << static_cast<int>(0) 
       << static_cast<float>(0.0) 
       << static_cast<unsigned char>(0) 
       << static_cast<char>('0')
  } -> std::convertible_to<T&>;
};
```

[Demo.](https://godbolt.org/z/35qr9aqM4)

Comment: I have created a topic for that answer, because I don't understand it. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69621855/mixing-delete-keyword-with-concepts-and-constraints