# Mixing delete keyword with concepts and constraints

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts, requires-clause, requires-expression

[In my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69585297/avoiding-implicit-conversion-with-concepts/69587497) I received an answer which suits me, but I don't understand how does it work.

Especially, I don't understand how `delete` keyword along with concepts remove overloads for `operator<<`.

(I will paste piece-by-piece, refactored version of the code from the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69585297/avoiding-implicit-conversion-with-concepts/69587497#answer-69587497).)

```
enum class LogLevel
{
    info,
    warning,
    error
};

template<typename T>
concept HasLogMethodReturningReferenceToSelf = requires(T v)
{
    {
        v.log(LogLevel{})
        } -> std::convertible_to<T&>;
};
```

So, here we define a concept, which checks whether a type has method `log()`, which takes `LogLevel` as a parameter and returns convertible to reference to self.

Then we delete `operator<<` overloads (block implicit function generation and explicit overloads) for overloads which have on the left-side of `<<` a type which satisfies `HasLogMethodReturningReferenceToSelf` and on the right-side of `<<` a type which is not a `std::string`:

```
template<HasLogMethodReturningReferenceToSelf T, class U>
requires(!std::convertible_to<U, std::string>) auto operator<<(T, U) = delete;
```

1. I don't understand when the overloads would be deleted? During "instantiation" of the concept for some specific type `T`? Because, not for each type which satisfies the criteria (it would break the codebase?)?

Because later, another concept is defined, which checks for output stream operator overloads for basic types:

```
template<typename T>
concept HasOutputStreamOperatorOverloadsForBasicTypes =
    requires(T v, unsigned unsigned_, int int_, float float_, unsigned char unsigned_char_, char char_)
{
    {
        v << "string literal" //
          << unsigned_        //
          << int_             //
          << float_           //
          << unsigned_char_   //
          << char_            //
        } -> std::convertible_to<T&>;
};
```

Finally, we define a `Loggable` concept:

```
template<typename T>
concept Loggable = HasLogMethodReturningReferenceToSelf<T> && HasOutputStreamOperatorOverloadsForBasicTypes<T>;
```

Normally, I would define one big `Loggable` concept:

```
template<typename T>
concept Loggable = requires(T v)
{
    {
        v.log(LogLevel{})
        } -> std::convertible_to<T&>;
    {
        v << "string literal" //
          << unsigned_        //
          << int_             //
          << float_           //
          << unsigned_char_   //
          << char_            //
        } -> std::convertible_to<T&>;
};
```

And then somehow restrict implicit conversion. I guess that the author of the answer had to split those `requires` expressions to two, because otherwise, when I use the latter `Loggable` definition and then `delete` the overloads after the definition:

```
template<Loggable T, class U>
requires(!std::convertible_to<U, std::string>) auto operator<<(T, U) = delete;
```

I get compile error:

> fatal error: recursive template instantiation exceeded maximum depth of 1024

2. Why?

Comment: Do you have an example of that answer working? Because unless I'm mistaken, `HasOutputStreamOperatorOverloadsForBasicTypes` requiring the base types to work does indeed break it: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/z4esEc1vx

Comment: @Frank the example, which you have added, does indeed work, because there are overloads missing for your `Logger1`, and this is what we want to catch. See: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/6G8x9rG8G

Comment: Oh I see. The list of types in question is so arbitrary that I thought you wanted "implicit convertion to std::string + no other implicit conversion + some arbitrary list of types that is defined on a per-logger basis". I didn't realise that `double` `short` `long long` etc... are **never** logable types in your design.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't understand when the overloads would be deleted? During
> "instantiation" of the concept for some specific type T? Because, not
> for each type which satisfies the criteria (it would break the
> codebase?)?

When we check whether `v << unsigned_` is well-formed in the requires clause, if your `Logger` class does not have the `unsigned` overload of `operator<<`, the global `operator<<` defined before concepts will be selected since `U` will be directly instantiated as `unsigned` and there is no implicit conversion, so it has a higher priority.

And because the global `operator<<` is deleted, so `v << unsigned_` is ill-formed and the constraint is not satisfied.